# Asking a question about the speed of light

Tags: grammaticality

Light travels at a speed of 300.000 km per second.

In order to ask about the speed of light, which one/s of these is/are correct:

A. How fast does light travel?
B. What is the speed light travels at?
C. How fast is light?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with any of these grammatically speaking, however the last one might elicit a different answer like: "It's very fast", since it's not necessarily asking about the speed.

Answer (score 4):

There's more than one way you can ask this question that makes sense.

> How fast does light travel? *Grammatically correct*
>
> What is the speed of light? **I find this one to be most commonly spoken**
>
> How fast is light? *Grammatically correct*
>
> At what speed does light travel? *Grammatically correct*

Those are a few fairly common ways to ask this question. They are all grammatically correct and mean, essentially, the same thing.